# Sending email gathering information from multidimensional hash table

Tags: powershell

I have output as shown below:

[image: ![enter image description here]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I am trying to get error values for each ID, and want to send a single email to the respective email details in hash table.

For example: Email to:sam@yahoo.com about the errors FirstName Missing and type should not be empty for ID:22148868.

I am not sure how it iterate this multidimensional hash table.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows the output from a `Group-Object` call.

The `Group` column doesn't show *hashtables*, it shows (stringified) *custom objects*, whose string representations happen to *resemble* hashtable literals.

Assuming that `$results` contains the output from your `Group-Object` call:

```
$results | ForEach-Object {

   # Get the email address.
   # Since all objects in the group have the same address in their .Email
   # property, simply query the first object.
   $email = $_.Group[0].Email

   # Collect the error messages from all objects in the group.
   $errMsgs = $_.Group.Error

   # Send an email.
   Send-MailMessage -To $email -Body $errMsgs ...

}
```